# check object type for UIButton

Tags: swift

How can I verify the object type?

the goal is to check an object custom type to check the value

```
@IBAction func showAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let question: Question = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        let rightAnswer = question.answers![question.answer]
        let subViews = self.view.subviews

        subViews.forEach { view in
            if view.isMember(of: AnswerButton.self) {
                let btn = view as! AnswerButton
                if btn.titleLabel!.text == rightAnswer {
                    btn.hightlight()
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

this is the UI. the button with the right answer should highlight if this is the right answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ArP.png)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if view.isMember(of: AnswerButton.self) {
  let btn = view as! AnswerButton
  if btn.titleLabel!.text == rightAnswer {
    btn.hightlight()
  }
}
```

Use [conditional downcasting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID341):

```
if let btn = view as? AnswerButton {
  // btn could be accessed as an instance of `AnswerButton` now
  if btn.titleLabel!.text == rightAnswer {
    btn.hightlight()
  }
}
```

If you don't need to downcast the button then you can loop over the subviews with condition:

```
for view in subviews where view is AnswerButton {
  // view is still treated as an instance of UIView but could be downcast to AnswerButton
}
```

Comment: `for case let view as AnswerButton in subviews {` will pick out just the `AnswerButton`s and they will be of the right type inside the loop.